# Calling map activity multiple time from parent activity and store data automatically

Tags: java, android-studio-2.3

I have two activities location activity and home activity and have two different buttons two launch location activity  btnGPSStartPoint and btnGPSEndPoint.

I want to store sendLocation in StartLatLong varibale on launching of location activity from btnGPSStartPoint and in EndLatLong variable on launching of location activity from btnGPSEndPoint.

In short i want to use activity as method with sendLocation as output

Plz help...

Home Activity:

```
        btnGPSStartPoint.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivityForResult((new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Location.class)),1);
            StartLatLong = getLocation;

        }
    });


    btnGPSEndPoint.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivityForResult((new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Location.class)),1);
            EndLatLong = getLocation;

        }
    });
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            LatLng result= data.getParcelableExtra("sendLocation");
            getLocation = result;
        }
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //Write your code if there's no result
        }

    }
}
```

Location Activity:

```
FloatingActionButton SaveLocation = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.location);
    SaveLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (MarkerPosition == null) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Please click on location first", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
            else {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Location.this);
                builder.setCancelable(true);
                builder.setTitle("Location");
                builder.setMessage("Latitude : " + MarkerPosition.latitude + "\n" + "Longitude : " + MarkerPosition.longitude);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Confirm",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                                returnIntent.putExtra("sendLocation",MarkerPosition);
                                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
                                finish();
                            }
                        });
                builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, solved

I called Location activity with different request codes and catches the result with if statement.

But looking for a way to use activity as a method

Home Activity:

```
       btnGPSStartPoint.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivityForResult((new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Location.class)),1);
        }
    });


    btnGPSEndPoint.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivityForResult((new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Location.class)),2);

        }
    });
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            LatLng result= data.getParcelableExtra("sendLocation");
            StartLatLong = result;
        }
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //Write your code if there's no result
        }

    }

    else if (requestCode==2){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                LatLng result= data.getParcelableExtra("sendLocation");
                EndLatLong = result;
            }
            if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                //Write your code if there's no result
            }
        }

    }
```